# CSS "Background-image: url(...)" doesn't work on my website

Tags: html, css, gitlab

I created my portfolio on Gitlab Pages. My `style.CSS` work partially. `background-image: url(..)` doesn't display in navigator. However, everything else seems to be working.
My content is in `public/img/.png`

I tried :

```
url(/img/.png);
url(public/img/.png);
url(/public/img/.png);
```

You can check my code here : https://medjaherirany.gitlab.io/resume/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide your CSS in the question instead of linking to it? It'll provide a more robust question and will lead to a faster answer. Also you can make something become stylied like code with back ticks (`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I went into your code on the inspector, use `background-image: url("../img/portrait0.png");` and it works. I will include a screenshot. This is used to go backwards in the directory.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly, you save me!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your CSS file you have used

```
figure {
  background: url(/img/portrait0.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 80% 111px;
  height: 727px;
  background-size: 690px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Change it to

```
figure {
  background: url("img/portrait0.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 80% 111px;
  height: 727px;
  background-size: 690px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Here actually your CSS says to look for img directory in the parent directory `of "https://medjaherirany.gitlab.io/"`

But your code is in `https://medjaherirany.gitlab.io/resume` That's why the browser was searching for `"https://medjaherirany.gitlab.io/img/portrait0.png"`
But actually it is in `"https://medjaherirany.gitlab.io/resume/img/portrait0.png"`

Here I changed the URL of background image and I got the image working.

[image: Console made it]

Hope this helped you. Feel free to ask any further doubts.
Happy Coding